# Highcharts - ensure visual continuity when dynamically updating chart?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to specify how data is "joined up" when dynamically updating a bubble chart in highcharts?
So that bubble "A" in this example disappears, "B" animates and "C" appears.

Initial data:

```
[
    {
      id: "A"
      x : 2 
      y : 2
      z : 2
    },
    {
      id: "B"
      x : 2 
      y : 2
      z : 2
    }
]
```

Updated data:

```
[
    {
      id: "B"
      x : 2 
      y : 2
      z : 10
    },
    {
      id: "C"
      x : 2 
      y : 2
      z : 2
    }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the point.remove() function, the point.update() function, and the series.addPoint() function to control the three different events.  To identify the point to remove/update, you can either use the index value of the point, or the chart.get() function.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.remove
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.get